# Mysqli retrieved table prints headers instead of data

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I tried to explain this as well as I could in the title, but with my current code instead of printing the data that is present in the database it prints the headers of each column instead (PO, Date, Job Name) for each row in the database. Since my database has two rows of values so far it has two copies of the row that just says
"PO Date Job Name", I can't figure out why it's printing the header instead of the actual data in the table. Any help would be great

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<?php
require 'classes/Mysql.php';
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('There was a problem        connecting to the database');

$query = 'SELECT "PO", "Date", "Job Name" FROM po_10152796 LIMIT 10';
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    ?>


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Job list</h1>
<table id="fairtable">
            <tr>
                <td>PO Number</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Job Name</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $rowitem['PO'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rowitem['Date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rowitem['Job Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your columns in your query are wrapped in quotes which are not the correct [identifier qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html):

```
SELECT "PO", "Date", "Job Name"
```

Second, since one of your columns contains a space, use ticks around it, and all of them while you're at it. You don't have to, but that `Job Name` column name **must** be wrapped in ticks, because of the space between both words.

```
SELECT `PO`, `Date`, `Job Name`
```

Plus, that should have thrown you an error having checked for errors, such as:

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

- Also make sure your file is indeed `.php` extension; *an insight*.
- At best, use an underscore to seperate them with `Job_Name` and renaming your column name to that name. That way you won't need the ticks around it, unless it's a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

---

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thanks for being so clean and concise with your answer! Really helped clear things up!

Comment: @NathanGeist You're welcome Nathan, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

You're actually selecting string values right now.

Instead of

```
SELECT "PO", "Date", "Job Name" FROM po_10152796 LIMIT 10
```

You should be selecting your columns by doing

```
SELECT `PO`, `Date`, `Job Name` FROM po_10152796 LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In here:

```
$query = 'SELECT "PO", "Date", "Job Name" FROM po_10152796 LIMIT 10';
```

You are selecting those strings, not the fields, try this:

```
$query = 'SELECT p.PO, p.Date FROM po_10152796 AS p LIMIT 10';
```